# Extracting values from a nested JSON file

Tags: python, json, extract

I am trying to extract values from air quality sensors to have them displayed on a device. I cannot extract nested values of temperature, humidity and PM sensors. How do I get them as separate keys and values?

I did install pandas ant tried some other solution:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://192.168.0.117/data.json'
df = pd.read_json(url, orient='columns')

print (df)
```

and

```
import urllib.request, json
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.0.117/data.json") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print (data)
```

What I get is a list of values:

```
{
  "software_version": "NRZ-2018-123B",
  "age": "28",
  "sensordatavalues": [
    {
      "value_type": "SDS_P1",
      "value": "18.40"
    },
    {
      "value_type": "SDS_P2",
      "value": "10.33"
    },
    {
      "value_type": "temperature",
      "value": "9.50"
    },
    {
      "value_type": "humidity",
      "value": "99.90"
    },
    {
      "value_type": "samples",
      "value": "1753691"
    },
    {
      "value_type": "min_micro",
      "value": "80"
    },
    {
      "value_type": "max_micro",
      "value": "793061"
    },
    {
      "value_type": "signal",
      "value": "-73"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I get them as separate variables?

Comment: what is your expected output may I ask >

Comment: E.g. returned temperature or humidity value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congrats on getting started with python! It's a great tool for data analysis.

butterflyknife is right, json_normalize is a good tool to use here.

I tried this locally:

```
import urllib.request
import json 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 

sample_data = '{"software_version": "NRZ-2018-123B", "age":"28", "sensordatavalues":[{"value_type":"SDS_P1","value":"18.40"},{"value_type":"SDS_P2","value":"10.33"},{"value_type":"temperature","value":"9.50"},{"value_type":"humidity","value":"99.90"},{"value_type":"samples","value":"1753691"},{"value_type":"min_micro","value":"80"},{"value_type":"max_micro","value":"793061"},{"value_type":"signal","value":"-73"}]}'

y = json.loads(sample_data)
y2 = json_normalize(y["sensordatavalues"])
```

That sample data is now y2, a dataframe that looks like this:

```
# >>> y2
#      value   value_type
# 0    18.40       SDS_P1
# 1    10.33       SDS_P2
# 2     9.50  temperature
# 3    99.90     humidity
# 4  1753691      samples
# 5       80    min_micro
# 6   793061    max_micro
# 7      -73       signal
```

Comment: Sorry for a rookie question, but the code you wrote works fine as long as data is input locally as a list

data = '{"software_version": "NRZ...} etc

When I try to define data as here:

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.0.117/data.json") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

What I get is:

in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict.

Logically, the data from the URL equals the '{software version...} etc, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten the json before reading it in to pandas. `json_normalize` seems to be what you need. Here's a tutorial on it:

https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-tutorial-flatten-nested-json-in-pandas